# No boot possible after power loss in hibernation

Tags: boot, power-management, hibernate

I tried to boot my system after a power loss in hibernation mode.
I got a lot of `I/O errors` and `unable to read superblock`.
I can't tell you which Ubuntu version I'm using as I can't boot it but as I update regularly it should be the current one. My hard drive is an sdd and I have a Lenovo Think Pad E560. It's no dual boot with Windows, only Ubuntu.

I've already tried to access the disk with a Ubuntu live usb but the disk-utility only says unknown partition for the whole disk.

The output of `sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sda` is

`Short INQUIRY response, skip product id` 
`A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting.`

To me it seems like the hibernation mode is kind of blocking the drive.

Has anybody an idea how to boot or access the drive? I willing to provide you with any information about my system which I can get by using an live usb.

I've already searched on several platforms but maybe I'm not using the right tags. Any link to help is also very welcome.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I/O errors almost always means a faulty drive and likely not recoverable by software tools. That said, neither hibernation nor suspension can cause it.

Comment: Thank you, ChanganAuto. I had a similar problem last year (the disk is less than 18 months old) and I'm wondering what causes such defects to be able to prevent them.

Comment: But for the moment I've to accept that I obviously need a new disk.

Comment: Drives are unpredictable. I've seen HDDs perfectly fine after more than 20 years and I've seen many fail in less than 3. Having 2 fail in a very short time could be bad luck but it isn't outside the statistical normal. But it can be something else at play or as a contributing factor like excessive writing and yes, hibernation, unlike suspension, tends to do that but in any case it's no different than many other operations that do the same writing.